# what does this derivative notation mean in General Relativity?

Tags: notation, general-relativity

in a class introducing Spacetime in General Relativity,

Given the following:

> $(1)$ $f$ is a function from $d$-dimensional manifold $M$ to $R$.
>
> $(2)$ $\gamma$ is a map from $R$ to $d$-dimensional manifold $M$
>
> $(3)$ $V_{\gamma,p}$ (so called 'velocity') maps a smooth function $f$ to an element in $R$: $V_{\gamma,p}=(f\circ \gamma)'(\gamma^{-1}(p))$
>
> $(4)$ $\gamma (0)=p$

the following derivation is made:

> $$V_{\gamma ,p}(f)=(f \circ \gamma)'(0)=(\underbrace{(f\circ x^{-1})}_{map: R^d\to R}\circ \underbrace{(x\circ \gamma)}_{map: R\to R^d})'(0)= \underbrace{({x\circ \gamma)^i}'(0) \cdot \delta_i (f\circ x^{-1})(x(p))}_{\text {What exactly is going on here?}}$$

I don't understand the final step in this derivation. Specifically, I don't understand what exactly is meant by the notation. **In another context, I would assume that it refers to a single element $i$ of the dot product of the gradient of $f\circ x^{-1}$ with the derivative vector of $x \circ \gamma$**. However, does it refer to the entire dot product here? If so, the notation is weird.

So what does the final part of the derivation mean exactly?

---

Should the final part of the equation simply be the following?

$$\sum_{i=1}^d\left(({x\circ \gamma)^i}'(0) \cdot \delta_i \left(f\circ x^{-1}\right)\left(x(p)\right)\right)$$

i.e. was it simply written down sloppily?